# Car Traceability

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I want to deploy a smart contract for tracing cars. For example, say I am producing 10 cars

Now what I want is to create a smart contract for tracing cars.

So my smart contract will have three features

RegisterCar {

carName:

carModel:

carVIN:

}

Check Status ( can be called using a specified key from the blockchain)

{

Features will be

carName:RegisterCar.carName

carModel:RegisterCar.carModel

Milage: AcceptOwnership.Milage

carVIN:RegisterCar.carVIN

currentOwner: transferOwnership.currentOwner(

isOK: Acceptownership.carStatus

}

TransferOwnership{

currentOwner:

nextOwner:

Authentication with a private key from the current Owner like a password

}

** for this part I want to require a passcode from the current owner to be transferred and the passcode needs to be updated when AcceptOwnership is completed.

In acceptOwnership a user can set up the password for transfer ownership.

AcceptOwnership

{

carStatus:

SalesDate:

Milage

}

Any recommendations regarding this?

How do I implement the part TransferOwnership which must ask the user for a passkey

and then in the new owner can set up the transferOwnership Passkey

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a password system as the user signs the transactions with its private key.

If I understand well your use case you want to :

1. The current car owner offers to a next car owner his car with `transferOwnership`.
2. The next car owner accepts the transaction with `acceptOwnership`.

One solution would be to use the `approve/transferFrom` pattern of the ERC721 standard (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) :

```
function approve(address _nextOwner, uint256 _carId) external payable;
```

This method would play the role of your `transferOwnership` function and is called by the current car owner.

```
function transferFrom(address _currentOwner, address _nextOwner, uint256 _carId) external payable;
```

This method would be the `acceptOwnership` function and is called by the approved next owner.

#### Remark

You seem to confuse structures and functions.

A car struct would be for example :

```
struct Car {
uint256 carId;
address carOwner;
...
}
```